# Where is the definitive list of crawled properties in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, crawled-property

Where is the definitive list of crawled properties in SharePoint 2016?

There also seems to be overlap of many properties so why are there so many alternatives?
see below:

e.g. Calendar Event Dates:

- ows_Start_x0020_date
- ows_EventDate
- ows_q_DATE_EventDate

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint 2016, The “ows_Start_x0020_date” is the default crawled property mapped to the default managed property “StartDate”.

When a crawled property is created, spaces are removed from the site column name, and then the following prefixes are added to the site column name to create the crawled property name:

For site columns of type Publishing HTML and Multiple line of text: ows_r__

For site columns of type Managed Metadata: ows_taxId_

For all other site column types: ows_q__

Per my test in my SharePoint 2016 environment, I create one site column named “myownercolumn” with “Date and Time” column type and add the site column to the content type, then add the content type into one document library, and then run a full crawl.

Then, there are two crawled properties in the search schema, one is ows_myownercolumn, the other is ows_q_DATE myownercolumn which is mapped to myownercolumnOWSDATE.

After running a full crawl, if the site column is the “Date and Time” type and added to the content type which is added to the list, then the crawled property will be “ows_q_DATE_” and “ows_” .

“ows_q_DATE_” is created and mapped to nameofcolumnOWSDATE automatically.

And the ows_ is for the list column after the content type is added to the list.

So, in your post the “ows_EventDate” and “ows_q_DATE_EventDate” are the crawled properties of site column “EventDate”.

More reference:

Automatically created managed properties in SharePoint Server.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj613136%28v=office.16%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Ok thanks, so the billion dollar question is where is the calendar END date property.  The ows_Start_x0020_date doesn't actually populate.  Only the ows_EventDate property which has no mention of 'start' in the column name. Very confused :/